# Virtualization inside VirtualBox (nested virtualization)

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox, hardware-acceleration

I have created a Debian VM (using VirtualBox in my Windows 10 host machine) and installed various features necessary for developing an android application. While installing Android Studio,

I noticed that in order to have the **accelerated performance mode**, I had to install KVM which led to me finding out that, **inside VirtualBox, hardware virtualization seems to not be supported**. A few minutes of googling confirmed that but most answers were a few years old.

1. Has anything **changed** since?
2. In Android Studio **without KVM**, is the speed difference **significant**?

Comment: I don’t believe VirtualBox supports nested virtualization.  To my knowledge only Hyper-V and (specific) VMWare products support it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware acceleration (accelerated performance mode), as the name suggests requires hardware assistance from the CPU (see Intel VT, not sure what AMD's equivalent is).

Within your Debian VM it's only aware the instruction sets provided by the virtual CPU (vCPU) opposed to the physical core so the accelerated mode isn't available.

Basically avoid nested virtualisation if you need the performance.

Why not just develop on the Windows 10 host? If you need a Linux environment try using the Windows subsystem for Linux functionality. That'd allow you to install Ubuntu and then the Android development suite within that. Suspect that'd provide a better experience.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The reason I wanted to use a VM is that there is a long list of stuff I have to install/configure, so I wanted to do it once and copy everything to some other hosts. Also the WSL is amazing but still a bit buggy. I guess I will try it now...

Comment: Could you use docker on your machine perhaps, instead of VBox?

Comment: Maybe I could, but I am afraid the learning curve is a bit too steep and my time really limited.

Answer (score 2):

As of VirtualBox 6.0, nested virtualization is supported but **you need an AMD processor** to use this feature. This feature is currently not supported on Intel processors.

Nested virtualization can be enabled in the VM settings, under **System** > **Processor**. More information is available in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/F12469/html/nested-virt.html).

Answer (score 2):

As of VB 6.1 (december 2019) Intel processors are now also supported :

Virtualization core: Support for nested hardware-virtualization on Intel CPUs (starting with 5th generation Core i, codename Broadwell), so far tested only with guest running VirtualBox

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F22853_01/F22856/html/ch03s01.html